# How to debug Tensorflow logits/label shape issue during 'fit' call?

Tags: python, tensorflow, debugging, tensorflow2.x

I'm trying to train a segmentation U-Net with TensorFlow. The dataset, images on my computer, is preprocessed prior to running the model and saved as Tfrecords.

So prior to training I load the tfrecords with `tf.data`. If I look at a single example, I get that:

```
ds_train = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(training_tfrecords).map(load_image_train, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
train_dataset = ds_train.cache().shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE).repeat()
one_record = train_dataset.take(1)
for i, (img, seg) in enumerate(one_record):
    print(f"BatchImg{i}: {img.shape}")
    print(f"BatchSeg{i}: {seg.shape}")
```

Output (6=batch size, 96=img dimensions, 1=channel dim):

```
BatchImg0: (6, 96, 96, 96, 1)
BatchSeg0: (6, 96, 96, 96, 1)
```

So far it looks good. But then when I try to start the training I get the following error:

```
model_history = model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=EPOCHS, steps_per_epoch=180)
```

Output:

```
ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 96, 96, 96, 16) vs (None, None, None, None, 1))
```

I'm not sure how to debug further here... Thank you for your help!

Comment: I see at least two main problems with this last output: the image shape (96^3) not replicated for the segmentation (labels), and the '16' in the logit that appears out of nowhere...

Comment: I would start from calling a model and ensure that its output shape ties to the label from dataset and to the loss function, e.g.: a = model(BatchImg0). I didn't work with U-Net. But it looks like 16 is output shape for this model. 16 could be a number of classes. Which loss function are you using ?

Comment: Hi @Andrey thank you for your response! Indeed I am troubleshooting this 16, it seems to be the output of my model currently.
Using `tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)`

Comment: Hi, Pierre. As far as I understand - binary cross entropy require output shape of 2 (an label shape of 2). You have output shape of 16 and label shape of 1.

Comment: I'm fixing the 16 back to 1 right now. For the loss I used `tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` with tf1 previously, but converting everything to tf2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Andrey pointed out (thanks!), I needed to check **not only my input image shape but also the output of the model (logits) shape**. The issue was only coming from the difference in shape between the logits and the segmentation ('16' vs. 1 in the last dimension). So the model output was incorrect. After fixing it (using `model.summary()` to find out what to do), everything ran just fine!